# Running Fuel Php in Azure

Tags: php, azure, fuelphp

I am trying to move a website from an apache2 site to an Azure hosted site. 
I configure Azure as a PHPWebsite. I copied the contents of my site into the Azure site.

I installed Pear PHP Not sure why but I was advised to do it. 
I then ran

> php composer.phar self-update

and

> php composer.phar update

and installed FuelPHP.

Now I am getting this error

> Warning: require(\classes\autoloader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\bootstrap.php on line 4 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '\classes\autoloader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\bootstrap.php on line 4

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that location `D:\home\site\wwwroot\app\bootstrap.php`?

Answer (score 1):

The path `\classes\...` will find to the absolute path `\classes\autoloader.php` in the file system in the windows OS, which is not the actual file path.

We need to relative path `classes\autoloader.php` or absolute full path `__DIR__."\classes\autoloader.php"` if the file path "classes\autoloader.php" is in the same directory with the `bootstrap.php`.

Additionally, we can have a simple test on Azure Web Apps to verify the issue:
if you have a `classes` folder with `autoloader.php` file and the folder is in the same directory with the test script,
`echo realpath('\classes\autoloader.php');` will return empty

`echo realpath('classes\autoloader.php');` will return the right full path

Comment: Both return the same result.

Comment: empty or full file path? And If it is convenient, could you please capture your directory structure?

Comment: it responded as follows 'realpath
\classes\autoloader.php'

Comment: Oh and BTW the file does not exist. And I cannot find it on our internal server either.

Comment: I suggest you can modify to `require('classes\autoloader.php')` or `require(__DIR__.'classes\autoloader.php')`. And check whether the file is exactly in the location.  And you can build your application on local first, to test the completeness, and then deploy to azure via GIT or FTP.

Comment: Fuel uses the constant COREPATH, defined in your index.php, to locale the framework classes. It should point to the /fuel/core directory in your installation, i.e. the folder in which base.php is located.